# IronPython get to internal class from C# dll

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm using IronPython for fetching inner classes from C# dll.
for example:

```cs
namespace Platform.CardHost {
    internal class ExtensionManager : IExtensionManager, IDisposable {
    //... other code
```

IronPython Code

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference('Platform.CardHost')
import Platform.CardHost.ExtensionManager
# raise ImportError: No module named ExtensionManager
# if it add to ref
clr.AddReference('Platform.CardHost.ExtensionManager')
# raise Error
# IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly
# Platform.CardHost.ExtensionManager
```

How can I import `ExtensionManager`? Or is this not possible?

Comment: why not making `ExtensionManager` public? You defined it as internal, so I don't see any reason for importing it. `The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.`is the definition for `internal`. If you want to use it in another assembly make it public..

Comment: it not my code ((, i can't change class. Can i disassemble dll, change and assemble it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So like I already wrote:

make `ExtensionManager` public if you want to access it from somewhere else than your assembly.
The definition of `internal`is

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.

what you could do, to make it only available for another assembly is, to make it visible for a friend assembly:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System;

[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("my_friend_assembly")]
internal class ExtensionManager : IExtensionManager, IDisposable 
{
}
```

else, I don't see any reason why making it internal but trying to access it from another assembly/your ironpython-script. Yeah, for friend assemblies, there are reasons, for sure.

**for your new update: "I can't change class":**

so maybe, the guy who wrote that class doesn't want you to import the class from elsewhere? That's the use of `internal`,`protected`,`private` and `public`.

Imho, it would be really bad to define in C# a class as `internal`, so you can't import it from C#, but IronPython still lets you import it.

for sure, you could try getting the code from the assembly, change it and make it again to a new assembly, like you wrote. But that's a lot of work and possibly in the end, it won't work.

Comment: i try to decompile dll. but file can't assemble without problem. I wrote to the guy, he say me use C# interface ICardHost. thank

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ***Matthias Burger*** for a fact that prompted the idea. 
i try to decompile dll. because the file were large after he disassemble, it can't assemble without problem.
I wrote to the guy, he say me use C# interface ICardHost.
here how i use it,  maybe for someone who meet similar problem.

```
clr.AddReference('Platform.CardHost')
from Platform import CardHost
from Platform.CardHost import ICardHost

host = CardHost.CardHost.CreateInstance(session)
# ExtensionManager is internal class but it available by interface
# here how to use C# interface
em = ICardHost.ExtensionManager.__get__(host)
```

as it in C#

```
// cardHost
public sealed class CardHost : Component, ICardHost

// ICardHost 
public interface ICardHost {
IExtensionManager ExtensionManager { get; }
```

Comment: like I already wrote: decompiling is a lot of work and in the end, it possibly may not work. And, for sure, using interfaces is the best solution (imo), that's why they're called "interfaces" :) - I'm glad, that I could help you. Happy coding.